# how to get list from a list which contains dict_values in python

Tags: python

I have a list which is having a set of key,values like

```
      {`namelist = [{'name': 'John'},{'name': 'Tin'},{'name': 'Mony'}, 
                    {'name':'Hilber'},{'name': 'Marge'}]`}
```

Iam tring to get list which is having only names like

```
       {`names =['John','Tin','Mony','Hilber','Marge']`}
```

I tried like

```
      {`names = []
         for i in range(len(namelist)):
           names.append(namelist[i].values())`}
```

it is giving output like

```
       {`[dict_values(['John']),
          dict_values(['Tin']),
          dict_values(['Mony']),
          dict_values(['Hilber']),
          dict_values(['Marge'])]
        `}
```

but i want only names in the list without dict_values tagging. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` from map-reduce (Please look for map-reduce in python for more details)

```
namelist = [{'name': 'John'},{'name': 'Tin'},{'name': 'Mony'}, 
                    {'name':'Hilber'},{'name': 'Marge'}]

result = map(lambda item: item.get('name'), namelist)
print(list(result))
```

In short map operation simply lets you map a collection of items into a different collection of items. It takes a function and at least one iterable as an argument. On each iteration, a single item is supplied to the function which must return a value. The value is collected which is of map type which can be converted using list().